# Zoho data structure setup for e-commerce referral program

Tags: zoho

Building custom integration for a client with their e-commerce store and Zoho. They essentially have a referral program, for the easiest explanation. When someone purchases, we need to keep track of who the referring person was in Zoho and credit them - I have this all available. They only sell 1 product so we don't need actual financial / sales data, just the number of units attributed to the person in Zoho. They eventually want to be able to have reports generated in Zoho to tell them how many units each person is doing per month, who is their best performer, etc.

All the potential referral people are stored as Contacts in Zoho. My task is simply getting the data from the e-commerce site into Zoho, I do not have to create any reports or anything within Zoho. I have no experience with the Zoho world so I am not quite sure where the best place to even put this data as there are so many different Zoho "things" to use. I thought about using Invoices, but again we don't necessarily need the transaction data just counts and when they happened to produce the above stated reports.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to reach someone at Zoho: Sales Orders are the right place to put this.